# lost password of stand alone system, domain controller crashed, cannot reset password

Tags: windows-xp, forgot-password, domaincontroller

During a network failure, our domain controller crashed and is no longer available. One of the users lost his password, and cannot remember it. How can I go ahead to help him as I dont have domain controller to reset his password?

Initial setup:
all computers connected through a domain controller.

Current Setup:
No domain controller.

Any help would be really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was closed. There was no way to do that without recreating Domain after the crash. No Resolution.